# How to construct a matrix with the following mapping

Tags: mathematics, transformation, graphics-programming, vertex-shader

How would I create a matrix that maps coordinates like so:

Near plane

```
x: [-3,3] -> [-1,1]
y: [-6,2] -> [-1,1]
z: 2 -> -1
```

Far plane

```
x: [-4,4] -> [-1,1]
y: [-4,4] -> [-1,1]
z: 0 -> 1
```

Visual
[image: coordinates]

Result:
[image: result]

My current solution is a transformation in a vertex shader like below, but if it's possible to use a matrix I can keep my shaders as is.

```
vec4 special_projection(vec4 p){
  float ty = 0.25 * p.z;
  float tx = 0.25 * p.x;
  float xz = (tx / 3.0) * (p.z / 2.0);
  float x = tx + xz;
  float y = 0.25 * p.y + ty;
  float z = -0.5 * p.z;
  return vec4(x,y,z,1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's take an initially unknown matrix, and multiply it by one of the points on your near plane:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c & d\\
e & f & g & h\\
i & j & k & l\\
m & n & o & p
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
-3\\-6\\2\\1
\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}
-3a - 6b +2c +d\\
 -3e -6f +2g + h\\
-3 i - 6 j + 2k + l\\
-3m -6n +2o + p
\end{bmatrix}$$

After the perspective divide, that becomes:

$$\frac 1 {-3m -6n +2o + p}\begin{bmatrix}
-3a - 6b +2c +d\\
 -3e -6f +2g + h\\
-3 i - 6 j + 2k + l
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
-1\\-1\\-1
\end{bmatrix}$$

Here you have 3 equations in 16 unknowns:

$$\begin{align}-3a - 6b +2c +d &= 3m + 6n -2o - p\\
-3e - 6f +2g +h &= 3m + 6n -2o - p\\
-3i - 6j +2k +l &= 3m + 6n -2o - p\\
\\-3a - 6b +2c +d - 3m - 6n +2o + p &= 0\\
-3e - 6f +2g +h - 3m - 6n +2o + p &= 0\\
-3i - 6j +2k +l -3m - 6n +2o + p &=0
\end{align}
$$

Now repeat this for each of the corners of your near and far planes, and you'll have \$3 \times 4 \times 2 = 24\$ equations in 16 unknowns. That's enough to plug this system of linear equations into a solver and come up with values for the 16 variables \$a\$ through \$p\$, giving you a matrix that satisfies this mapping.

Comment: Here are my equations: https://pastebin.com/4J3TRSzD. Cannot find any solutions in wolfram alpha or symbolab. Maybe I do not understand, or there exist no solution.

Comment: @user3346597 We can remove the perspective contraction on the y axis by skipping the division by w. Or, correspondingly, by multiplying the y coordinate by w at the end of our vertex shader. That would turn the second equation in the example above into -3d-6f+2g+h = -1. Try applying that to the y row of all of your equations, and then check whether that modified system of linear equations has a solution.